# Why am I getting "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'civicrm_activity.source_contact_id' in 'field list'" on Activity View after upgrade to 4.6.7?

Tags: activities, drupal-views, issues

For the past few upgrades I've needed to apply a fix for activity views detailed here: 
https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=33513.0

Today I upgraded to 4.6.7 and got the same error, but when I make the changes in the fix mentioned above, I still get the error.

Does anyone have any insight about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 4.6.7, the fix Sudha Bisht suggested appears to only be partially applied.

Line 49 had not been removed.

If I edit civicrm_handler_field_link_activity.inc and remove line 49, it appears to resolve the issue.

Comment: Looks like this is still a problem in 4.6.9.

Answer (score 2):

Have you applied this https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/pull/298 ?. As error you have mention is recently resolved.

Comment: Here is a link to the JIRA in case that adds more info - https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15008